# Add gwt remove service button not responding

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm clicking on the button to add a new gwt remote service (I'm pointing at a client directory), and the button doesn't respond. Nothing happens and a service isn't created.

On other projects it is working.

I'd be happy to provide more details but I'm not sure which details are relevant.

See image:

[image]

Comment: explain in more details??what does it mean add a new gwt remote service

Comment: I want to add a new RPC in my GWT module.

I'm pointing on a package that's under the client side, and I click GWT alt+insert -> Google Web Toolkit -> Remove Service.

Then the picture I've added shows up, but nothing is added.

Comment: can u plz add the image properly? did u added the configuration in web.xml

Comment: The image is now added properly.
The issue happens before configurations happen in the web.xml

Comment: i m still not able to see the image